# PHP: Insert data in MySQL every after the comma is detected

Tags: php, mysql

Example

Name: `John, Doe, Jane`

Message: 
`Hi, This is a message`

How can i save each data with the name separated with comma in database? output must be.

```
Name | Message
John | Hi, This is a message
Doe  | Hi, This is a message
Jane | Hi, This is a message
```

Comment: use SELECT CONCAT (Name , " | " , Message) FROM `table` WHERE 1

Comment: i mean, in php code to separate each word from Name given. The output below must be the output in my database.

Comment: you can use explode(",", $name) and in loop you can insert data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use explode function to explode and foreach to insert

```
 $names_all="John, Doe, Jane";
 $names=explode(",",$names_all);
 $msg = 'Hi, This is my msg';
 foreach($names as $name)
  {
   if($name!="")
    {
             //insert query using $name and $msg
    }     
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$name="John, Doe, Jane";
$msg="Hi, this is massage.";

$namearray=explode(',',$name);
for(Si=0;$i<count($namearray);$i++){
    insert into table_name values('$namearray[$i]','$msg')  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can explode the string by `,` using the `explode()` function which will return an array. And then loop through the array and insert into the database for each name.

Something like this:

```
$names="John, Doe, Jane";
$message="Hi, This is a message";

$names_array=explode(",", $names);

foreach($names_array as $name){

    $sql="INSERT INTO table ('name','message') VALUES ('$name', '$message')";
    if(mysqli_query($conn,$sql)){echo "$name was added to the database";}    
}
```

*Note: Use prepared statements and avoid the pain :).*